# Please help explain fork() in Operating System

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system

**Given the following piece of code:**

```
main(int argc, char ** argv) 
{
    int child = fork(); 
    int c = 5;

    if (child == 0) 
    {
        c += 5;
    } 
    else 
    {
        child = fork(); 
        c += 10; 

        if (child)
            c += 5;
    }
}
```

**How many different copies of the variable c are there? What are their values?**

So, the answer turned out to be there are three (3) processes:

- `c` value of parent process is 20,
- `c` value of child1 process is 10,
- `c` value of child2 process is 15,

Can someone please help me explain this in detail? Line by line would be great!

I see that there is another question addressing fork(), but I want to understand this lines of code specifically and how the answers came out like that.

Comment: I understand, but for this specific code I want to understand how those answers came out.

Comment: Short answer, each successful call to `fork()` creates a new process.  The new process is identical to the old one in every detail except for the value returned by `fork()` (it returns 0 in the new process, but in the original, it returns the pid of the new process.  The pid always is > 0.)  For the long answer:  See the "duplicate."  The answers there spell it out in detail.

Answer (score 0):

The first child process executes:

```
int child = fork(); 
int c = 5;
    /* since child == 0 */
    c += 5;
```

The second child executes:

```
int child = fork(); 
int c = 5;
    /* since child != 0 */
    child = fork(); 
    c += 10;
    /* child == 0 now */
```

The parent process executes:

```
int child = fork(); 
int c = 5;
    /* since child != 0 */ 
    child = fork(); 
    c += 10;
        /* since child != 0 */
        c += 5;
```